# Custom templates and validation with Deform and mako

Tags: pyramid, deform, colander, colanderalchemy

I am using deform in a project that uses pyramid with mako as a templating engine. I rewrote the templates for the widgets I need. I am using a modal for one of the forms so I wrote the mako template and the set the form widget with

`form.widget = widget.FormWidget(template='modal')`

The form works fine for the initial render, but when calling the validation block

```
 try:
   appstruct = self.my_form.validate(controls)
     
 except ValidationFailure as e:
   return dict(e.render())
```

`e` doesn't render the modal template, but rather the default form. How does make the validation form render using the same template as the form?

---

Right now I am using this to work around it...it shows the warning when there is an error, but does not display the particular errors on each field:

```
except ValidationFailure as e:
  form.error = e.error
  form.field = e.field
  return dict(form.render(e.cstruct)
```

---

The `modal` is the popup retail example from deform demo. The schema node just has a couple of text input fields.

Adding example:

facilities view:

```
@property
def form(self):
  schema = SQLAlchemySchemaNode(Facility)
  return Form(schema, buttons=('submit'))

@view_config(route_name="facilities", renderer="facilities.mako")
def index(self):
  form = self.form
  form.widget = widget.FormWidget(template="modal")

  if 'submit' in self.request.params:    
    try:
      controls = self.request.POST.items()
      appstruct = self.facility_form.validate(controls)

    except ValidationFailure as e:
      return dict(form=e.render())

  return dict(form=form.render())
```

The mako template then just injects the html:

```
{ form | n }
```

Comment: Are you trying to replicate this example in DeformDemo's [Popup and retail rendering](https://deformdemo.pylonsproject.org/popup/)? Can you provide a reproducible example? The validation from the demo is in the [`render_form` view method](https://deformdemo.pylonsproject.org/allcode?start=101&end=115#line-101).

Comment: Also did you know that you do not have to rewrite widget templates into Mako, Jinja2, or any other template language?  [Chameleon generates Python strings that you can include in your main template](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/deform/en/latest/templates.html#alternative-template-engines).  You might need to add necessary JavaScript and CSS link references in your page template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with it for a while I came up with this solution (not sure if it is optimal). Before returning `e.render()`, set the form attributes on `e.field`

```
@view_config(route_name="facilities", renderer="facilities.mako")
def index(self):
  form = self.form
  form.widget = widget.FormWidget(template="modal")

  if 'submit' in self.request.params:    
    try:
      controls = self.request.POST.items()
      appstruct = self.facility_form.validate(controls)

    except ValidationFailure as e:
      e.field.widget = widget.FormWidget(template="modal")
      e.field.set_widgets({}) ## if using different from defaults
      e.field.formid = "my-popup" ## and any other non default attributes.
      return dict(form=e.render())

  return dict(form=form.render())
```